# How getting all properties (Parent and child class) in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot

How can i do to get all properties
coming from client(Postman) json in spring
boot?

For exemple i have classe

```
Class A{

  String a;
 
}

Classe B extens A{

  String b;
  
}

Class C {
  long id;
  List<B> c=new arraylist<>();
}
```

In my controller

```
@Postmaping()
test(@Requestbody C c){

 Sysout(c);// I want get all properties a and b

}
```

i only got the b properties  not a

My json

```
{  "id":1,  "c":[{"a":"a","b":"b"}] }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have Class B extending from Class A. Therefore B is more specific. If your RequestBody contains string a and string b

```
{
   "a":"valueA",
   "b":"valueB"
}
```

you have to change your request Body to receive Class B.

```
@PostMapping("/some/endpoint) 
public void test(@Requestbody B b){
    System.out.println(b); //  contains valueA and valueB
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question was not correct so I edited it

Comment: We  since your Datamodel now looks different can you provide the JSON with witch you are doing your POST call. I guess the error is within the structure you are using

Comment: Ok I edit my question

Comment: I have tried it out. Works fine as long as there are getters and setters. Have you implemented those? Your Code does not show. If it is related to getters/setters it might be relevant if you leave the default or set your properties to public/private.

Comment: Yea I already have all getter/setter but I'm getting only the properties of the super class

Comment: The problem came from the toString method of the child class :D 
thank you for your answers

Comment: Glad that you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

After a hard debugging match, I just realized that I was wrong  @Override the toString() method of the child class.

It was simply necessary to add super.toString()  to child class

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() +
                "b ='" + b+ '\'' +
               
                '}';
    }
```